# error when importing panddasgui into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandasgui

after I installed pandasgui in a conda virtual environment with Python=3.8, I try to import pandasgui with `from pandasgui import show` and here is the error that I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\users\pmore\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-1-488ae1300181>", line 1, in <module>
    from pandasgui import show

  File "c:\users\pmore\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandasgui\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandasgui.gui import show

  File "c:\users\pmore\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandasgui\gui.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandasgui.store import PandasGuiStore

  File "c:\users\pmore\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandasgui\store.py", line 1
    from __future__ import annotations
                                      ^
SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just found that I'm using Python v 3.6 when I should be using 3.7 or higher. Just upgraded my python version and it works fine. Thank you